# How to extract whole rows of data in Excel if it contains a subtring within a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The entire workbook is a few sheets long, however essentially I'm working with a base sheet that has around 8000 or so lines data with about 10 columns or so. The end goal of this project is to be able to input a start date, end date and a keyword and then be filtered one last time with another keyword. So far, I've been able to filter down the original data within the date range and within the first keyword. The problem arises now when the keyword is within a block of text that varies and is never quite the same. For example, one row contains

> 12T Q1FY23 Unscheduled/Emergency Maintenance

While another row contains

> 12T Q4FY23 ERT Spill Stations

There are hundreds of variations of this, but there, including ones that don't start with "12T". The starting data is subject to change so I can't quite use tables in excel and filter it that way, as once you apply a filter then the table won't update if new data is input as the source data, unless there is a way to do this and I just don't know how. So ultimately, I need the same filter that can be used on a table that says "contains" and/or "does not contain" as formulas. Formulas seem to work well with this dynamically/subject-to-change source data, so I'd like to keep it with formulas, as I have done with the filtering previously with the date range and then with the other keyword. The difference between what I want now and what I did for that other keyword is that it was a static keyword that isn't embedded within a string like the "12T". Please let me know if this is too vague or if there's any more material needed to help answer this question. Attached is a sample image of a what I'm working with on the original sheet. I'd like to be able to extract the rows containing only "12T", and not the one's "12T-M", for example, using only a formula. Assume that the data starts at A3 and ends at C8. I should also mention, just to be completely clear, I'm trying to copy these rows dynamically into another sheet so that it can be nicely viewed with only the relevant information and data.

[image]

To be extra clear, I first filter it the original data with the following formula:

> =INDEX(Sheet1!$A$6:$N$6796, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF('12T'!$H$11,Sheet1!$G$6:$G$6796), MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$A$6:$N$6796),ROW(Sheet1!$A$6:$N$6796)), ""), ROWS(B3:$B$3)), COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A$6:A6))

The "Sheet1" referral contains the original data and "12T" refers to the sheet that contains the filtering keywords (the dates and the number keyword). This formula extracts all of the rows of the original dataset in Sheet1 that contain a specific keyword, in this case its "5351 - Facilities: Maintenance: Building". These extracted rows of data are deposited as an array (Entered with ctrl+shift+enter) in a new sheet labeled "Xtract".

In this same sheet, I then filter out this array with the date range in mind. With the starting and ending date, I first calculate the number of instances that a date falls within the date range with the following formula.

> =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$671>=Q2)*($A$2:$A$671<=Q3))

I use this result in the following formula in conjunction with the filtered data (filtered with the previous keyword) to filter it further so that I only get the rows of data that have their date in the date range.

> =FILTER(A2:O671,(A2:A671>=Q2)*(A2:A671<=Q3),"No data")

This is also entered as an array, and is also in the "Xtract" sheet. With this filtered data set, I want to filter it one last time, so that only the rows of data that contain, for example, "12T" or "728M" in one of the cells (in which the respective cell can be written as "12T Q1FY23 UEM") can get extracted and placed into a final array. All of this is automatically updated simply by entering the values in this section I have shown below.

[image]

I can't use a table to filter the data, at least not that I know of, because if I filter a table by this logic ("contains '12T'" and "does not contain '-M'" to get only rows that contain 12T but not 12T-M or anything that's not 12T) then once I change the date range or the other keyword, the table won't update properly. If there's anything else I can add to help clarify, please let me know.

Comment: It would seem: `=FILTER( yourRange, (LEFT([column with code],3)="12T")*(LEFT([column with code],5<>"12T-M") )` would give you a filter of your range of data.

Comment: Is "yourRange" referring to the whole set of data or only the range of the column? My column containing the "12T" and such is in another sheet, so it would be sheet!T:T, or would it be sheet!T2:900, which is the range of the whole thing? I'm asking because I'm receiving a "#VALUE!" error.

Comment: Yes - it could be. Without more info on your worksheet and what you want to do with the filtered data, it is hard to be specific. It could be that you are filtering the xxx.xx as the yourRange.

Comment: I just want the filtered data in another location. I'm automating the filtering with formulas by typing in a range of dates (start and end date) and then another filtering term, which leaves me with something similar to what I showed above. With that data, I want to filter it further to only have the 12T rows on one sheet, the 12T-M's on another sheet, and so on.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick Is this how the formula would work? I'm still getting the same "#VALUE!" error. `=FILTER(XtractFilters!R2:AF900,(LEFT(XtractFilters!T:T,3)="12T")*(LEFT(XtractFilters!T:T,5<>"12T-M")))` Additionally, will this work if there's anything following the -M? Such as "12T-M Q1FY23 UEM".

Comment: Ahh ok - i see you got there. Yes, the problem was that your ranges must be the same size, so R2:R900 will throw an error when filtering it with T:T. The filter reference must be T2:T900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and referencing my old work/internet, I found the formula to answer my problem. I understand this might not be the most clear since I can't quite provide the excel workbook I'm working with, but the goal of this was to automate all of the filtering so that no matter if data is added or not, when you change the filters, it will stay updated correctly. From the filtered data that I had already worked with, all I had to do to put it into another sheet was use the following formula:

```
=FILTER(XtractFilters!T2:AF900,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("12T *",XtractFilters!T2:T900)))
```

This finds all of the data containing a specific substring, which in this case specifically was "12T ", denoting the space as well. So all of the filtered results are then filtered once again so that only the rows where "12T " was found get returned. The range is just the entire range of data and then the column is the one containing the text where "12T " could be found.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the left containing formulae: "=find("12T ",B1) and copy down.
Note the space after T.
Rows matching that will have 1; rows not matching will have #VALUE! so you can sort on them.

P.S. if #VALUE! is ugly, you can use =NOT(ISERROR(FIND("12T ",B2)))

Comment: I haven't tried this method but I just found a solution which I'm posting now. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @zsalya's answer: Add a column to the left, add this formula to the first cell and copy down:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("12T",B2:M2,0)),"Found", "Not Found")
```

No need for spaces after the T.

If the above formula is in column A, I'm then  assuming that any column from B to M could contain the target value.

In column A then, you will get a list of values like this:

[image: Picture of Column A]

We can then use Excel autofilter on column A to view all the rows which contain the target value.